How can I accept/reject individual changes in VS Code's 'Source Control' view?
In VS Code's 'Source Control' view, how can I accept or reject individual changes?
I have attempted:

right-clicking
looking for mystery meat in the gutter
Reading Microsoft's documentation on the source control UI.

I expect to be able to right-click a change and accept or reject it. Maybe VS Code simply lacks this ability but that seems very strange for a source control UI.


select a change and use right click

Thanks @rioV8. Right clicking without highlighting seemed natural because the changes are already in a block, so it wasn’t obvious I had to select first.

maybe they have chosen this because often changes lead to multiple regions and then you have to right click multiple times and be sure not to forget a region
